# How do I find the buckling strength?

Tags: finite-element-method, buckling

I am running something called cell periodicity study in comsol, which finds the material properties of a model. It is done by applying a uniaxial compression load, and performing a nonlinear buckling analysis - this gives the stress strain curve you see below. You can think of the material being for example epoxy, and I asked colleague how we define the stiffness, and was told it is when the material stiffness becomes 30% of the initial one, and they told me it has nothing to do with strain??

So how can I tell when the material has lost 70% of its stiffness? Especially when it has nothing to do with strain.

[image]

Comment: Why not ask your colleague? He/she *knows* what he/she meant. We can only guess.  The idea of "stiffness that has nothing to do with strain" makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: They told me something along the lines of "Buckling strength is determined by structural stiffness not strain. As a result, you will know the buckling strain aswell"

Comment: How do you define the stiffness in your case? Usually while dealing with buckling it is more common to talk about stability, not about strength or stiffness.